MacOS: edit .plist files in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/
I am trying to setup tftp server, but have a difficult time doing so.
I found a possible solution, which suggests editing /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist, however, I cannot find a way to do so.
I have tried the following:

Manually editing: sudo vim /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist - file is read-only.
Copy file to another directory, edit it there, then copy back (as described in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72701725) - Operation is not permitted.
Changing the file via defaults: defaults write -g /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist -string '<dict><key>Sockets</key><dict><key>Listeners</key><dict><key>SockFamily</key><string>IPv4</string></dict></dict></dict>' - I get an error defaults[40264:23017013] Could not write domain /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/tftp.plist; exiting.

There are various other possible solutions on other forums, which all seem to be outdated and not working currently.
Is there a way to change that file?

Most of /System is protected both by System Integrity Protection, and also by being on a readonly, cryptographically sealed volume. It's extremely hard to change anything there, and almost never necessary. In this case, all you need to do is put the modified file in /Library/LaunchDaemons instead of /System/Library/LaunchDaemons. The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72701725 actually says to do this, it just doesn't emphasize it.
